# Closed-form solution to $\frac{\ln x}{x} = k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, special-functions

> What is the solution in $x$ to $$\frac{\ln x}{x} = k ?$$

I suspect this has something to do with the Lambert W function, since that's used in solutions of the form $x\ln(x) = k$, but the Wikipedia definition of $W$ is a little too abstract for me to apply this to $\frac{\ln x}{x} = k$.

Comment: Perhaps you could consider substitution $y=\frac{1}{x}$, then $\frac{\ln x}{x} = -y\ln y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** If we change variables to $y = \frac{1}{x}$ and rearrange, we produce
$$y \log y = -k , $$
which has precisely the form that the original question remarks can be handled by the Lambert W function.

NB that many people (myself included) would not consider the Lambert W function to be closed.

Comment: Quick question, what does NB mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene